# Convert list of arrays to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of numpy arrays that I'm trying to convert to DataFrame. Each array should be a row of the dataframe.

Using pd.DataFrame() isn't working. It always gives the error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input.

Is there a better way to do this?

This is my current code:

```
list_arrays = [ array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 00]], dtype='uint8'), 
                array([[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 00]], dtype='uint8')
              ]

d = pd.DataFrame(list_arrays)

ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [143]: pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(list_arrays))
Out[143]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [144]: pd.DataFrame(list(map(np.ravel, list_arrays)))
Out[144]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

> Why do I get:
>
> `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input`

I think `pd.DataFrame()` tries to convert it to NDArray like as follows:

```
In [148]: np.array(list_arrays)
Out[148]:
array([[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)

In [149]: np.array(list_arrays).shape
Out[149]: (2, 1, 9)     # <----- NOTE: 3D array
```

Comment: Thank you! All of them works. But i wonder why i was getting that 2-d error.

Comment: For me, `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(list_arrays))` just caused all my arrays to flatten and be 1 dimensional instead of "row stacking" them. Therefore, I recommend just use `pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack(list_arrays))` . It was a couple seconds on 140k rows x 17k columns

Answer (score 8):

#### Alt 1

```
pd.DataFrame(sum(map(list, list_arrays), []))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

#### Alt 2

```
pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack(list_arrays))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can using `pd.Series`

```
pd.Series(l).apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x[0]))
Out[294]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

lst = [np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int),
       np.array([[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(lst))

#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
# 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 1  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  0
```